Drawing hierarchical clustering in scikit-learn
I have an embedding matrix of shape (4312, 1024) (corresponding to 1024-dimensional embedding vectors of 4312 English sentences). I want to perform a clustering of these vectors and to visualize the results (in order to see if the distance threshold that I chose was good enough).
The clustering is done using:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, metric='cosine', 
                                compute_full_tree='auto', 
                                linkage='complete', 
                                distance_threshold=0.2,
                                compute_distances=True)
clustering = model.fit(embeddings)
print(f'Number of clusters: {clustering.n_clusters_}')
print(f'Labels:\n{clustering.labels_}')
# count unique labels
unique_labels, counts = np.unique(clustering.labels_, return_counts=True)
print(f'Number of clusters by counting: {len(unique_labels)}')

# Sort in descending order of counts
sorted_indices = np.argsort(-counts)
unique_labels = unique_labels[sorted_indices]
counts = counts[sorted_indices]
print(f'Unique labels: {unique_labels}')
print(f'counts: {counts}')

The results of the print is:
Number of clusters: 1714
clustering.labels_:
[ 460  820  245 ... 1030  112 1367]
Number of clusters by counting: 1714
Unique labels: [ 410  352  229 ... 1039 1041 1713]
counts: [55 42 33 ...  1  1  1]

I obtained 1714 clusters, and the largest cluster contains 55 points. If I increase the distance threshold to 0.25, then the number of clusters decreased to 1395. I want to know which sentences have been merged if distance_threshold=0.25 (compared to distance_threshold=0.2), so I plot the results for 0.2, following the Scipy's official example and did:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram

def plot_dendrogram(model, **kwargs):
    # Create linkage matrix and then plot the dendrogram

    # create the counts of samples under each node
    counts = np.zeros(model.children_.shape[0])
    n_samples = len(model.labels_)
    for i, merge in enumerate(model.children_):
        current_count = 0
        for child_idx in merge:
            if child_idx < n_samples:
                current_count += 1  # leaf node
            else:
                current_count += counts[child_idx - n_samples]
        counts[i] = current_count

    linkage_matrix = np.column_stack(
        [model.children_, model.distances_, counts]
    ).astype(float)

    # Plot the corresponding dendrogram
    dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)

plt.title("Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram")
# plot the top three levels of the dendrogram
plot_dendrogram(clustering, truncate_mode="level", p=3, distance_sort='ascending', show_leaf_counts=True)
plt.xlabel("Number of points in node (or index of point if no parenthesis).")
plt.show()

Results:

I have two questions please:

I chose the distance to be cosine, which is between [0,1]. How is it possible that the distances from the leaves to their parents are larger than 1? Is it due to numerical errors?

The function dendrogram seems to draw the tree top-down. Is it possible to draw bottom-up: the clusters are the leaves? This would make more sense to me because I would like to start from the clusters and see how they would merge depending on the distances between them.


Update: I was not very clear about the second question. What I would like to have is not the orientation of the graph (i.e., not a geometric transformation). Let me be more specific. There are 1714 clusters with the following number of points, in decreasing order: counts: [55 42 33 ...  1  1  1]. I would like the drawn tree to have:

Exactly 1714 leaves at the bottom (with labels (55), (42), (33), etc. In the above plot, you can see that this is not the case: the labels are (1231), (692), etc.)

Then above the leaves, let's say level 1: the merged leaves

Then above level 1, let's say level 2: the merged level-1 nodes

etc. up until level p.


This will not necessarily reach the root and thus will create disconnected components, but that's precisely what I would like to have.
Thank you very much in advance for your help!


I chose the distance to be cosine, which is between [0,1]. How is
it possible that the distances from the leaves to their parents are
larger than 1? Is it due to numerical errors?

That's not correct. Cosine distance is in the range [0, 2]. Cosine similarity is in the range [-1, 1], and cosine distance is defined as 1 - similarity.
Example of a distance higher than 1:
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.cosine([1, 0], [-1, 1])
1.7071067811865475

Docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances.html

Thank you very much for your answer! Good catch on cosine distance! Regarding the "orientation" of the tree, actually this is not what I meant. Could you please check the update text in my question? Thanks again for your help.

@f10w Oh, I see. My mistake. I don't have enough familiarity with AgglomerativeClustering to answer that question.
